# Invoking Extension methods as a static method - Good, or bad style?

Tags: c#, coding-style, extension-methods

For a project I'm working on, a programmer wrote some generally useful extension methods on `Decimal` and `string`.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public decimal ForceStringToDecimalInSomeSpecialWay(this string str)
    {
        // ...Magic...
    }
}

public static class DecimalExtensions
{
     // Similarly useful methods.
}
```

In a code review I'm doing for another teammate, however, I notice that instead of invoking the extension method as a...well, extension method, like such:

```
Decimal foo = someString.ForceStringToDecimalInSomeSpecialWay();
```

...they instead invoked it as a static method.

```
Decimal foo = StringExtensions.ForceStringToDecimalInSomeSpecialWay(someString);
```

While it's *syntactically a correct invocation that actually works,* I **question** whether it is good practice, or not.

It seems to me that, if we want to use a static helper class that provides useful tools and invoke it as a static method, that's OK.  But when you're deliberately extending another type with a new method, invoking that new method as a method on a static class is somewhat questionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb383977.aspx) are syntactic sugar. At compile time they will be called like rest of static methods. *(Like your second code snippet)*.

**IMO,**  It is better to call them like a simple method like:

```
 someString.ForceStringToDecimalInSomeSpecialWay();
```

so that you can leverage the feature of Extension method, otherwise there is no point in having them as extension methods in first place.

Imagine if you have to call LINQ extension methods like:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 };
var result = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Where(list, r => r != 5));
```

That just looks <strike>horrible</strike> bad.